# I want to mount an alarm motion sensor in the corner of a room - what do I need to know?

Tags: walls, drill, security, alarm

I have an alarm system that I'm going to fit myself, the motion sensors will be mounted in the corner of the rooms - presumably as the screws are relatively short (maybe a 1 to 1.5 inch long) this is a worry-free exercise and things like wires will generally not be an issue?

It's a new build property in the United Kingdom if that matters, thank you.

Comment: You need to layout your plan, get your equipment and then ask specific questions  about specific problems you're encountering. This isn't a general forum.

Comment: Wires ? Who uses wired systems these days? I agree with jack you should have the device it may use self adhesive pads to mount.

Comment: When you set the alarm make sure the cat is out... :) guess how I know...

Comment: In a  properly built house, 1"  screws should not reach any wires inside the wall or ceiling. You will want to be careful drilling if you are installing anchors.

Comment: @JACK the specific question was whether or not I needed to be aware of electrical or piping works behind a wall if I am using 1-1.5 inch screws, this is clearly in the topic of my question.

Comment: @EdBeal the system itself is not wired, it's a wireless alarm system that does come with both rawl plugs and screws, and adhesive 3m sticky pads, but they advise to use the screws to ensure sensors do not fall off the wall as the pads dry out.

Comment: @AlaskaMan thank you - the first proper answer! I'm not using anchors per se, just plastic wall plugs as the sensors are not heavy.